Extract a zip file with password protected in Azure ADLS
I have a zip file which is password protected in azure ADLS container.
Want to unzip it and move the files to different container
I tried with copy activity. It is giving error.
"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorUnzipInvalidFile,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The file 'Myriad_DataConnect_AON_04-16-2024.zip' is not a valid Zip file with Deflate compression method.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.IO.InvalidDataException,Message=The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.,Source=System.IO.Compression,'",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "cpy-SFTP-ADLS-myriad",
"details": []

Please give me the solution.

ADF doesn't appear to support password protected zip files, and it appears you'll need to work around it yourself

According to  this:

Currently, Data Factory does not support reading and generating password-protected files.

An alternate workaround is to unzip the password-protected zip file using an Azure function.
Create an HTTP trigger Azure function with the code below:
import azure.functions as func
import uuid
import os
import shutil
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient
from zipfile import ZipFile

storageAccountConnstr = '<storage account conn str>'
container = '<container name>'

# Define local temp path; on Azure, the path is recommended under /home 
tempPathRoot = 'd:/temp/'
unZipTempPathRoot = 'd:/unZipTemp/'


def main(req=func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    reqBody = req.get_json()
    fileName = reqBody['fileName']
    zipPass = reqBody['password']

    container_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(storageAccountConnstr, container)

    # Download zip file 
    zipFilePath = tempPathRoot + fileName
    with open(zipFilePath, "wb") as my_blob:
        download_stream = container_client.get_blob_client(fileName).download_blob()
        my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())

    # Unzip to temp folder
    unZipTempPath = unZipTempPathRoot + str(uuid.uuid4())
    with ZipFile(zipFilePath) as zf:
        zf.extractall(path=unZipTempPath, pwd=bytes(zipPass, 'utf8'))

    # Upload all files in temp folder
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(unZipTempPath):
        for file in files: 
            filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
            destBlobClient = container_client.get_blob_client(fileName + filePath.replace(unZipTempPath, ''))
            with open(filePath, "rb") as data:
                destBlobClient.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
    
    # Remove all temp files 
    shutil.rmtree(unZipTempPath)
    os.remove(zipFilePath)

    return func.HttpResponse("done")


Run it from  Azure Data Factory. For more information, you can refer to  this SO answer

@Anuradha Joshi Check if below/above provided solution works for you?
